# How does Django guarantee a middleware's __init__ to be called only once?

Tags: python, django, middleware, django-middleware

Django's documentation:

> Unlike the process_* methods which get called once per request, `__init__` gets called only once, when the Web server responds to the first request.

How does Django guarantee the middleware object is initialized only once? The Web server can start multiple instances of python interpreter to handle requests, right?

Comment: I imagine it means once per interpreter instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means once per interpreter instance. Note the implementation:

```
class WSGIHandler(base.BaseHandler):
  # ...
  def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    # ...
    if self._request_middleware is None:
        self.load_middleware()
```

You can read [`django/core/handlers/wsgi.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py) and [`django/core/handlers/base.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py) (esp. `Basehandler.load_middleware`) for more details.